# Ignore git repository when building a Python source-distribution package with setuptools

Tags: python, git, setuptools

I am trying to learn how to create a Python source-distribution package with setuptools.  I thought I understood that a package is a directory containing the file `__init__.py` and modules in that package are simply Python source files in that dir.  Hence, when simplified, my development directory looks like

```
.
├── newFile.py
├── OldCode
│   ├── testPackage2.py
│   └── testPackage.py
├── package
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── module1.py
│   └── module2.py
├── README.md
├── setup.py
├── test.f90
├── testPackage.py
└── .git/
```

where `package` contains the modules of my package.  My problem seems to arise because I want to ship `package/module1.py` and `package/module1.py`, but I also have a git repo that contains those files as well as the other .py files in the tree above (which I use to develop and test the package), and even a Fortran source file.  In addition, my (Gentoo) system has the package `setuptools_scm` installed in addition to `setuptools`.

It took me several hours to find out that running `./setup.py sdist` will simply ignore whatever configuration I type into `setup.py` (without warning), even though I `import setuptools`, not `setuptools_scm`.  In `setuptools.setup` I tried setting `packages, package_dir, py_modules` and `use_scm_version=False`, but none of these worked.  Is there a way (other than breaking my system by forced uninstalling the depencency package `setuptools_scm`) to tell `setup.py` to ignore my git repository rather than itself?  (I tried `exclude *` in `Manifest.in`, but then even `setup.py` is excluded.)

Comment: Can we see a [mcve]? Just a small repository that we can clone and test with and without `setuptools_scm`…

Comment: @phd Thanks for caring - here's my [example repo](https://github.com/AstroFloyd/setuptools-example).  A workaround is to tell ```setup.py``` to temporarily rename ```.git/``` - please comment that line in/out.  Only ```package/module[12].py``` are supposed to be included in the dist file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a workaround to disable `setuptools_scm` in `setup.py`:

```
from setuptools_scm import integration
integration.find_files = lambda p: []
```

The entire `setup.py` now looks like:

```
#!/bin/env python3

from setuptools import setup

from setuptools_scm import integration
integration.find_files = lambda p: []

setup(
    name='Package',
    description='A Python package',
    author='AF',
    author_email='AF@mail.org',
    url='https://hitgub.org/AF/package',

    packages=['package'],

    version='0.0.1',
    license='GPL',
    keywords=['package']
)
```

Comment: The problem was reported long ago at https://github.com/pypa/setuptools_scm/issues/190 and closed with resolution "wont fix". :-( They [recommend](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools_scm/issues/190#issuecomment-351181286) the same fix.

Comment: Thank you, this is a much more subtle workaround than mine :-)

Comment: The drawback of this solution is that the published package gets `setuptools_scm` as a dependency.